# Unable to install Enterprise inHouse provisioning profile on mac

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, in-house-distribution, mobileprovision

I have created `Apple Enterprise developer account` via referring this [blog.](http://johannesluderschmidt.de/provision-ios-ipa-app-for-in-house-enterprise-distribution/2993/) I am able to create distribution certificate, APPID and inHouse provisioning profile successfully. I have shared this distribution certificate (using keychain export to `p12` files) and inHouse provisioning profile(`.mobileprovision` profile) with other mac system from where I have to create ipa file. On this mac system, I am able to install distribution certificate but while installing `.mobileprovision` profile got below error.

[image: Error popup]

Any idea what I missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issues has been solved, May be there was some corruption might happen while sharing provisioning file on the other mac system. I have regenerated provisioning profile from apple portal and transferred to another system through the mail. I am able to install regenerated provisioning profile on the other mac system successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which Xcode you are using, but assuming you are using Xcode5 or 6, i suggest you use the automatic provisioning profile sync feature.

Just go to Xcode>Preferences and select the Accounts tab.

If you don't have any Apple IDs account signed just click on the '+' button on the bottom left and select 'Add Apple ID...', put the id and password that you use to log on the apple developer.

After that just click on the 'View Details...' button on the bottom right, and your signing identities and provisioning profiles should appear there. If they don't, just click on the bottom left refresh button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to share my credentials on other mac system.